# Is it possible to have a smart switch control a wired switch

Tags: electrical, smart-switch, smart-home

I have an older house, where running the new wires I need is challenging. I have a light that is on a switch at the top of the stairs, and I would like to add a switch at the bottom of the stairs also. So, my question is if there is any possible solution using smart devices such that I can maybe use a wifi lightbulb that talks to a switch downstairs, but also toggles if used with the current, upstairs switch? Or maybe both switches can be smart switches - convert the existing one, and make the new one a smart switch (but both on separate lines) - i.e. Have one smart switch directly in line with the light and the other totally separate?

Some additional details to better explain the situation is that the current, upstairs lighting is on a subpanel already upstairs. I can easily add the required power and switch to the downstairs from the basement. The issue is connecting the two disparate wirings to the same light.

Comment: What's the issue with just changing the light switch to a smart light switch? "smart" simply implies WiFi enabled, so you can already control that anywhere in the house.

Comment: @Nelson I just made an edit to explain the 2nd option is to have both be smart to a smart bulb. Would that work if they are on a separate lines though? I can't find anything readily about this situation...

Comment: Sounds like you want 3 way switch set up. 3 way is having two switches in different location controlling the same light. Maybe you already have cables for that.  Answer if Yes,

Comment: Yes. That is what I want. But getting wires to the other plug is problematic

Comment: lets assume you have one light to control. You could use smart light bulb, and control it either with 2 remote or with voice on you phone.

Comment: @Nelson Smart does **not** imply WiFi enabled. Or rather, all WiFi-enabled switches are smart switches, but not all smart switches are WiFi enabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use a smart wired switch with a wireless remote. For example, with Lutron Caseta, you can use a Pico remote to control. Since it is battery powered/wireless, you can mount it to the wall, nearly indistinguishable from a wired switch, or use it separately like a TV remote.

The one catch is that many smart switches (the wired parts) need neutral in the switch box. That is part of current code in most locations, but historically has not been the case. The only way to tell for sure is to open up the existing switch box and see what wires are there. Neutral is normally white, but a white wire on a switch is not always neutral. If you are not sure, upload a picture and we can usually figure it out.